# App crashes at the second start, wont keep the key in memory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory

```
public String SavedPassword;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int n = 1000 + rnd.nextInt(9000);
                    String str = "";
                    str = Integer.toString(n);
                    SavedPassword = str;
                    String pass = str.toString();
                    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                    tv1.setText(pass);
                    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

                }
            });
             Button btn2  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
             btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     String pass = SavedPassword;
                     TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                     EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
                     String passc = edt.getText().toString();
                     if (pass.equals(passc)) {
                         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Photos.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     } else {
                         tv2.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
                     }
                 }
             });
        }
```

So, I want the first `button btn1` to make a key, and store it, after that I want the button to be disabled , `button 2 (btn2)` should be the LogIn one, and it should compare if the key is equal with the password you enter in `EditText`, if so, should send you to Photos.class, does that the first time when you run the app, (without the disable part because I dont know how to implement it yet) but the second time I open the app and put the "key" as password it will crash the app, I doesnt store the key in memory...

How can I fix this without using a database?

Comment: You need to write the key to a file.  That can be a db, a shared preference, or just a normal file.  But it needs to be stored and read from the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic guide you can follow: https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

I added some code below that should help you I think.  You'll have to double check if the syntax is all good, I didn't run it anywhere.

Basically I have it checking shared preferences first, to see if you have any passwords saved.  If you don't, I disable the second button.  If you do, I enable the second button.  Also SavedPassword gets set to the value.

```
public String SavedPassword;
@Override

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();

SavedPassword = pref.getString("stored_password", null); // getting String
if(SavedPassword == null) {
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
} else {
   bt2.setEnabled(true);
}


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int n = 1000 + rnd.nextInt(9000);
                String str = "";
                str = Integer.toString(n);
                SavedPassword = str;
                editor.putString("stored_password", SavedPassword).commit(); // Storing string
                String pass = str.toString();
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv1.setText(pass);
                Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

            }
        });
         Button btn2  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
         btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String pass = SavedPassword;
                 TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                 EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
                 String passc = edt.getText().toString();
                 if (pass.equals(passc)) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Photos.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 } else {
                     tv2.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
                 }
             }
         });
    }
```